# Combine 2 hexadecimal characters from file and convert to decimal

Tags: c++, hex

I am trying to combine two hexadecimal characters from a file into one hexadecimal and then convert to decimal/integers. I read the whole line from the file as a string and parse it into its individual chars (as each hexadecimal represents a separate entity), but one entity is two hexadecimal characters and I am trying to figure out to combine them. So in the file at elements 4 and 5 I have hexadecimal values of 0x1F and 0x01 and I am trying to combine them to make 0x011F (reserved direction).
Here is a sample of the code(working in C++):

```
std::string fileline;
unsigned char tempchar;
tempchar = fileline.at(3); //Sample of parsing individual chars
std::cout << (int)tempchar <<std::endl; //Displaying the correct value
//This is where I am having problems
unsigned char newchar[2];
//From the file, fileline.at(5) = 0x01 and fileline.at(4) = 0x1F
//Trying to get the value of 287 from these two elements
newchar[0] = fileline.at(5); newchar[1] = fileline.at(4);
//This is where it goes wrong and I dont know how to combine the two separate elements
```

Comment: If the two numbers are, individually, l and h and are 1 or 2 digit hexadecimals then the combined number is h * 256 + l. Simples! The rest is down to formatting.

Comment: What if I had more then 2 numbers? I am very new to using hexadecimal so this is all new to me

Comment: How many more numbers?

Comment: could be anywhere from 2 - 10, thats why I am trying to write a C++ function to do it

Comment: Unfortunately any more than 8 numbers will overflow a single 64 bit integral type. So my approach will probably be unduly complex.

Comment: There's not actually any hexadecimal here at all, it's just how your file viewer chooses to display it.  The file itself is binary.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you require the conversion of hexidecimal numbers that will overflow intregral integer types.  For this case, you need to use a library (or make one) that does such tasks.

The [GNU MP library](https://gmplib.org/) is a good place to start.  You can instantiate an `mpz_class` with your hex string, and you will get a functionally equivalent type with the value you want (see [this API example](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers.html#C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers)).  You can then use it in arithmetic or print it as a decimal string.